# Query Builder : Retrieve entities from the last X Months

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I am Trying to retrieve all `Facture` from the last 3 Months for a single user, I figured out the SQL approach but i have hard times applying this logic to query builder , I am using Symfony3-3.

```
$now = new Date('now');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
   $qb->select('f')
      ->from('Facture', 'f')
      ->where('f.doDate BETWEEN :old AND :now')
      ->andwhere('f.userId =:id')
      ->setParameter('old', ($now-90))
      ->setParameter('now', $now);
      ->setParameter('id', $user->getId());
```

This is the query I am trying to achieve :

```
SELECT * FROM Facture WHERE (f.DO_Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()) AND f.clientId ='?someone's id?'
```

**NOTE : I tried DQL but I had too many errors I couldn't handle.**

Comment: What are the errors returned?

Comment: @Veve It don't remember exactly , but as I remember from the debug , it's something about constraint and date pricesely about $now-90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (i guess you are in your Facture repository) :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('f');
$qb->andWhere(
       $qb->expr()->between('f.doDate', ':startDate', ':endDate')
    )
  ->andwhere('f.userId =:id')
  ->setParameter('startDate', new \DateTime('-90 days'))
  ->setParameter('endDate', new \DateTime());
  ->setParameter('id', $user->getId())
;
```

Comment: You are right I am in myFactureRepository , I ll give it a try.

Comment: I got this error :`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 22 near '(f.doDate BETWEEN': Error: Class '(' is not defined.|`

Comment: and if you try this : 

`$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('f')
  ->andWhere('f.doDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
  ...
;`

Comment: How would the query builder know f signifies entity : `Facture` ?

Comment: Because you are in your repository. And if you set the repositoryClass on your entity